# Piping into csvcut

Tags: csv, wget, pipe

Is this valid piping into csvcut - manual does not cover this scenario:

```
cd /home/kaku/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/ && wget "https://fakeurl.com/Download?file=fdsa34" | csvjoin --outer -c VendorStockCode,sku dicker_scraped.csv | csvcut -c Vendor,VendorStockCode,StockDescription,PrimaryCategory,SecondaryCategory,TertiaryCategory,DealerEx,StockAvailable,overview,specs,multi_images > dd_joined_cut_test5.csv
```

Edit: it seemed to be either timing out or producing zero-byte files - I'm not sure if this is related to a syntactical error or something else.

Essentially, this is tested and works:

```
cd /home/kalugi/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/ && wget "https://fakeurl.com/Download?file=fdsa34" -O dd.csv && csvjoin --outer -c VendorStockCode,sku dd.csv dicker_scraped.csv > dd_joined.csv && csvcut -c Vendor,VendorStockCode,StockDescription,PrimaryCategory,SecondaryCategory,TertiaryCategory,DealerEx,StockAvailable,overview,specs,multi_images dd_joined.csv > dd_joined_cut22.csv
```

But creates unwanted intermediary files and unnecessarily clutters the directory.  So I'm wondering if piping would work.

The problem is with

`wget "https://fakeurl.com/Download?file=fdsa34" | csvjoin --outer -c VendorStockCode,sku dicker_scraped.csv | csvcut ...` is that you're not following the format and specifying two files in succession, but rather, one of the files - and it must be the first one, corresponding with VendorStockCode field - is being piped in.  I'm not sure if csvjoin is designed to do this, though I've seen [other things](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/csvcut.html) piped in.

Comment: Is there an error with your command? What is your issue? Please [edit] and clarify your quesstion.

Comment: @DavidPostill  Edit: it seemed to be either timing out or producing zero-byte files - I'm not sure if this is related to a syntactical error or something else.

Comment: `wget` will write to its stdout if you specify `-O -`. I don't know `csvjoin` at all. I don't know if there's some similar option to make it read its stdin; but you can try to specify `/dev/fd/0` or `/proc/self/fd/0` as one of the input files. If the tool doesn't seek through the file, this may work.